# Which is the fastest way to get YearMonth from a datetime field from a table that contains 10M rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the year and month of a `datetime` column. For this I have come up with the following methods. Please note am using SQL Server 2019.

```
CONVERT(INT, FORMAT(A.dtmBilledDate, 'yyyyMM'))

CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.dtmBilledDate, 112), 1, 6))

YEAR(A.dtmBilledDate) * 100 + MONTH(A.dtmBilledDate)
```

There could be some other methods also. I need the net output datatype to be integer. Now out of these formats which is the fastest way to retrieve a dataset that contains like 500,000-600,000 records.

Whenever I run the time keeps varying, some times I get it in 4-8 sec sometime it goes to 16 sec. By the way I ran in a production server.

Comment: *"Now out of these formats which is the fastest way to retrieve a dataset that contains like 500,000-600,000 records."* You are in a *far* better position to test this thus us. I will, however, note that `FORMAT` is known to be a slow performer. I also *assume* that these are all expressions in the `SELECT` and **not** the `WHERE`/`HAVING`.

Comment: If this query is going to be happening a lot and needs to be fast, you could try creating an expression-based index or calculated column based on one of those, and checking the query plan for your query to confirm it's used.

Comment: @Larnu I guess you did not understand me. The problem I face is each time I run the same query the same output come with different times. So what am looking for is a comment or reply from who might have similar kind of experience. Anyways thanks for the hint on FORMAT.

Comment: Many things can affect the speed of a query. Other locking processes, I/O availability, CPU usage, RAM usage, query plan caching, are just a few.

Comment: You can simplify the second option - convert(int, convert(char(6), A.dtmBilledDate, 112)) or cast(convert(char(6), A.dtmBilledDate, 112) as int).  The third option would seem to be the faster option - but it comes down to testing.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your suggestion. one problem is that I don't need the day, only the year and month is needed.

Comment: style 112 for convert returns YYYYMMDD - converting to char(6) returns the first 6 characters which is YYYYMM.  Where did I include the day?